# Full CSS3 support for every browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know this is somehow a hard question or at least you probably think something like "Is he serious?", but anyway I ask it.

When I say all browsers I mean: IE6+, FF3+, Safari 5+, Chrome 13+, Opera 10+

Since Safari, Chrome and Opera are IMO browsers that are mostly used by people that really care about updates, I would even accept to only support even higher browser version.

I would like to take css files that are written in standardized css3 according to the w3c specification and generate a set of css and js files(probably also some files for different browser versions) that would get the css3 features work as expected.

So do you think, in general, that it might be possible to do something like that, or does something maybe already exist?

I would also appreciate if you have any suggestions, hints or some resources for me to get started.

**EDIT**

Since some people did not really understand what I meant and rated my question down I though I should have to make some clarifications.

I am asking whether you think it is technically doable(even with some overhead), to transform any set of standardized css3 files(current version of the w3c spec) into css, js and make the currently specified css3 features work as expected. If not, or if you already know that there might be problems or so, then please share that knowledge with me.

For example the rounded corners feature could be supported in older browsers by generating images for containers and use some wrappers around a container. This is way more efficient than using javascript polyfills.

I just want to hear opinions and reasons why this might be difficult in some situations. Maybe something like "I don't believe Feature XY to work in Browser AB because that feature can not be mimicked at all with the possibilities you have in that browser! The reason is ..."

So what do you think about it?

Comment: See CSS3Pie, Modernizr, and similar scripts.

Comment: Take a look at [Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills)

Comment: If you are talking just about prefix, you can try a simple solution: http://prefixr.com/

I do not recommend CSS3Pie.. it consume a lot of memory.

Comment: Modernizr is NOT going to give you CSS3 support, it tells you what is NOT supported in current browser

Comment: http://selectivizr.com/ adds a lot of css3 selectors to old IE

Comment: You should take a few steps back and try to have a better understanding of front-end development.

Comment: I am aware of modernizr, selectivizr and other js polyfills, but what I am asking is, if you think that a transformation in general would be possible. Of course I would have to make use of some libs to get things working, but what I want is code generation that is optimized for a specific browser version.

Comment: @ScottSimpson what do you mean exactly?

Comment: "So do you think, in general, that it might be possible to do something like that" Maybe two or three years later. Currently only a handful of modules have been standardized, there are dozens more still in draft and *more are being added all the time*.

Comment: Considering we've only seen the W3C equivalent of a feature-incomplete alpha of CSS3, it would be very unrealistic to expect such support for any current version.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov -- You may want to consider progressive enhancement or graceful degradation before trying to support CSS3 in all browsers. Honestly, there is no reason to support CSS3 fully in all browsers. That is the job of the browser vendors.

Comment: Doable it may be, but I think it is a **bad** idea. It involves giving the oldest and, at the same time, the slowest browsers the largest amount of code, so, in the end, you're not providing a better experience for the users of those browsers, but quite the opposite. A lot of people are not going to notice that some rounded corners are missing, but they are going to notice if the page takes a lot to load. And they might even decide it's not worth the wait and close it before they even see your rounded corners.

Comment: Of course it might be a bad idea to enable full CSS3 support for older browsers depending on what kind of features are used and how often. I dropped my idea meanwhile since I don't want to waste time on that but focus on my main business.

Answer (score 1):

[Polyfills](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill) are available to fill in features missing in older browsers.

I'm not aware of a generalized / automatic technique to transform an arbitrary CSS3 file, but many things you would do with HTML5 / CSS3 can also be accomplished using suitable polyfills.

For a good list of polyfills see

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Comment: Thanks for that, I am already aware of polyfills, but as I asked, I am looking for opinions about if it was possible in general, to transform css3 files to a set of files that fully enables css3 features in the mentioned browser versions.